# represent register YMM0 in variable in gcc

Tags: gcc, simd

I'm trying to represent the value that's in the ymm0 register as a variable in gcc.

I have tried this code:

```
register __m256 _YMM0_r asm ("ymm0") = _YMM0;
```

But i get this error message:

```
encryptor.c:72:17: error: data type of ‘_YMM0_r’ isn’t suitable for a register
  register __m256 _YMM0_r asm ("ymm0") = _YMM0;
```

Is there some other type than __m256 that I should use for the 256 bit registers?

gcc version i use is: gcc-6.real (Ubuntu 6.2.0-5ubuntu12) 6.2.0 20161005

Comment: Did you read https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Vector-Extensions.html. If that does not work, let the compiler do the register allocation.

Comment: I have now, and that was interesting, but it didn't really help me with the problem as far as I can see.

Comment: According to the [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Local-Register-Variables.html): *The only supported use for this feature is to specify registers for input and output operands when calling Extended asm.*  Maybe by posting the asm (and constraints) someone can find you a solution for your problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This was an simple case of not using the right flags to the compiler.

The code works fine if you compile it with the -mavx2 flag.